# Use vm.$on to listen to event emitted from child in vue.js 2.0

Tags: vue.js

I've been through the vue.js events section on events but it seems to only give examples of how to listen to events using the vm.$on handler within html.  Between that and the new changes for 2.0 I'm unsure how to simply transmit a event from child -> parent.

I need to transmit an event because after parent receiving i want to broadcast it to another child.

I'm using single page components, this is my setup:

```
// parent
export default {
  mounted: function () {
    this.$on('myEvent', function (msg) {
    console.log('caught in parent', msg)
  });
 },
 components: {
  'child': child,
 },
}

// child
this.$emit('myEvent', true)
```

How can I receive this event on the parent vm please?  Note, I don't want to use $on in the html.  I want the event receiving logic in the vm where it should be.

Thanks,

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`Vues` documentation on `$emit` is not very comprehensive, however, there are a few ways to do this. Firstly you have to `$emit` on the vue model you want to send the message to if you want to use `this.$on()`, so if you are sending from a component you can emit to the direct parent using:

```
this.$parent.$emit('myEvent',true);
```

However, this can become problematic if you have a long chain of parents because you have to `$emit` up the child chain, so in that case you can use a Vue instance as a bus:

```
// In the root as a global variable so all components have access
var bus = new Vue({});
```

Or if you are using single file components.

```
window.bus = new Vue({});
```

Then in the receiver:

```
bus.$on('myEvent',() => {
   // Do stuff
});
```

And in the emitter:

```
bus.$emit('myEvent',true);
```

Finally, if you find you `app` getting too complex for a simple bus then you can use `vuex`:

https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/index.html

Comment: Ok i went for the bus which seems like the sanest option.  Thanks for the pointer, i know the docs mention the bus but thought i could get away without needing it.

Comment: Solve it by use this.$praent.$emit to pass data from child to parent.Thanks

Comment: Well, I can't realize how to call parent method from func where 'Do stuff' is. It seems bus instance context :/

Comment: instead of `bus` you could just use `this.$root` - the root instance of Vue.