# vm.$on listener isn't firing from the parent mounted() method

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

It seems very simple but not working for me. I am trying to fire event from a child component and listen to it from the parent component using the `mounted()` method by using the `vm.$on()` [instance method](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-on) but it's not working.

For example, I have created a very basic [Vue CLI App on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-browser-emlgz?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) to reproduce the issue. Any help would be much appreciated.

Parent component: `App.vue`

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <HelloWorld />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$on('icecream', () => console.log('not good for children'));
  },
};
</script>
```

Child component: `HelloWorld.vue`

```js
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h3>Emit event from child and listen from parent</h3>
    <button @click="emitAnEvent()">Emit</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  methods: {
    emitAnEvent() {
      this.$emit('icecream');
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind! I was able to figure it out based on the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40487807/3313563). I had to `$emit()` event directly to the `$parent` like the following:

```js
this.$parent.$emit('icecream');
```

While this could be a bit problematic in different scenarios, it's completely fine on my case.

Answer (score 1):

There's also another option to handle the `$emit()` written in the [Vue Documentation here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitting-a-Value-With-an-Event).

```
<HelloWorld v-on:icecream="CatchIceCream()" />
.
.
.
methods: {
    CatchIceCream() {
        console.log('not good for children');
    }
},
```